# Socket.io not disconnecting on sleep

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I can't seem to find a way of having the socket emit the disconnect event when the computer enters sleep mode. Is there any way of catching when this happens on the server side? e.g. the disconnect event is handled like this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {[...]});
```

Comment: doesn't the client sleeping fire disconnect on the server?

Comment: No, haven't had that happen yet sadly

Comment: How long did you wait to see if the server saw the disconnect?  The server will have to notice that it is no longer receiving ping packets from the client.  That could take a little bit of time.

Comment: 7h, and it didn't fire a disconnect, and the disconnect event didn't fire. Is there something else I should be listening for?

Comment: I am having a similar problem on mobile. The socket.io client does not disconnect from the server when the user closes the browser application, switches to another application or even puts the device to sleep. Does anybody have updates on this?